# Extract numbers from multiple lines

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex which will extract the numbers from the following lines:

```
9013071329

MISSES ADAMS

PLEASE SUBMIT ID

9013071337

LITTLE ADAMS

PLEASE SUBMIT ID
```

`((.|\n)*)` seems to get me the whole passage, and I think `\d{10}` should return the numbers. Could someone help in putting the two together?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Good question...  Truthfully I don't know...  I'm using a piece of scanning/imaging software that has a feature where you can use regex to extract from OCR text.

Comment: @Mel: And how is this program called? There are many different regex flavors (hint: most likely it is something like `^\d+` in multiline mode).

Comment: The numbers can be matched with just `\d+`. The rest depends on what "feature" you have.

Comment: Well, can you check documentation of OCR application to see to what extent it support regex? It may have very basic support so need to know before suggesting you a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure what language you are using, but to get matches in multiple lines, you just need to add the /g flag, like this:

```
/\d{10}/g
```

In Javascript it looks like this:

```
text.match(/\d{10}/g);
```

I also recommend using this site to test your regexes: http://regexr.com/

Comment: It isn't always true, sometimes it can be a specific function (like in PHP), or a checkbox in an apps.